# Creating a diagonal shaded area in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I want to have a shaded diagonal area on a chart. Unfortunately, the `fill` attribute only fills the area that is vertically between two lines, and does not extend outwards to the edge of the chart, which results in this:[image]

As a workaround I can use a single line with a large `borderWidth`, which properly fills the entire area:[image]

However, `borderWidth` is specified in pixels, meaning that its width relative to the chart data will change depending on the display resolution.

How can I create a shaded area that covers the whole diagonal and whose width is specified in terms of the chart axes, not pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure your last points fall outside of the chartarea so the line contiues to keep going it will fill correclty:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 20
      }, {
        x: 30,
        y: 0
      }],
    }, {
      label: '# of Points',
      fill: '-1',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 15
      }, {
        x: 25,
        y: 0
      }],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'linear',
        min: 10,
        max: 20
      },
      y: {
        min: 0,
        max: 20
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah, this worked, thank you.

Comment: Hmm, this has caused a new problem. Now that there's a maximum on the Y axis, data points on the top edge are being cut off. Look at the blue dot in these two images:

With no maximum: https://imgur.com/a/agfMKek
With a maximum: https://imgur.com/a/Du0B0GZ

Comment: Then you increase the max,  but you will need to make sure you still keep some points outside of scale range for the shadow so you might need to place them further away too

Comment: I don't want the maximum to be greater than 100, since I think that looks bad and is a waste of chart space. I just want the data point to render above the chart lines, like it did before I set a maximum.